# C++ Addition Operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is my method of adding 2 Duration objects together in the format `(HH,MM,SS)`.

```
    inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Duration& d){
      return ostr << d.getHours() << ':' << d.getMinutes() << ':' << d.getSeconds();
    }

    Duration operator+ (const Duration& x, const Duration& y){
        if ( (x.getMinutes() + y.getMinutes() >= 60) && (x.getSeconds() + y.getSeconds() >= 60) ){
           Duration z( (x.getHours() + y.getHours() + 1), (x.getMinutes() + y.getMinutes() + 1 - 60), (x.getSeconds() + y.getSeconds() - 60) );
           return z;
        }
        else if (x.getSeconds() + y.getSeconds() >= 60){
           Duration z( (x.getHours() + y.getHours()), (x.getMinutes() + y.getMinutes() + 1), (x.getSeconds() + y.getSeconds() - 60) );
           return z;
        }
        else if (x.getMinutes() + y.getMinutes() >= 60){
           Duration z( (x.getHours() + y.getHours() + 1), (x.getMinutes() + y.getMinutes() - 60), (x.getSeconds() + y.getSeconds()) );
           return z;
        }
        else{
            Duration z( (x.getHours() + y.getHours()), (x.getMinutes() + y.getMinutes()), (x.getSeconds() + y.getSeconds()) );
            return z;
        }
    }
```

In my main method i have:

```
  Duration dTest4 (01,25,15);
  Duration result = dTest4+dTest4;
  cout << result << endl;
```

Unfortunately when i run the program i get this error:

```
  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Duration const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVDuration@@@Z) referenced in function _wmain 1>C:\Users\...exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I want to be able to add two times together in individual entities. Ie. The hours together, then the minutes, then the seconds. Hence the `if-else` to deal with when 2 sets of minutes exceed the 60min cap of an hour...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh, it looks like you are creating something terrible. I recommend you go post this code on a code review website. To me it looks like converting boolean value to string and checking its length to determine whether it was false or true ("false" has 5 characters, "true" got only 4).

Comment: I'd also recommend you break your problem down to the bare minimum. It will get your answers faster. Everything between the { and } could be considered fluff. Try a simple example first.

Comment: I'm aware its a lot easier to convert the whole thing to seconds and then add them, but this is the only way i could think to do it where the hrs, mins and secs are treated seperately.

Comment: Is your inline method in the .h header, including body?

Comment: Where is the constructor for `Duration`?

Comment: Ouch... You should put the condition when both minutes and seconds overflow as the first condition. Otherwise it will never be executed!

Comment: Your `operator<<` is `inline`, but your `operator+` isn't. If they are both in the header, one of them is wrong. If they are both in the CPP, the other is wrong. If they are both in the CPP, you can get the error message you describe.

Comment: Thanks Rob, Turns out that was the issue. I just needed to remove the `inline` in the .cpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here: `cout << result << endl;`
You haven't defined an overloaded version of `std::ostream& operator<<` for writing your `Duration` object to an ostream. Something like this should do it:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Duration& rhs)
{ 
os << "Hours: <" << hours_ << ">, ";  
os << "Minutes: <" << minutes_ << ">, "; 
os << "Seconds: <" << seconds_ << ">"; 
return os; 
}
```

Comment: The << overloading you just had up was perfect and did the trick. Obviously it was my << overloading method causing the problem. All sorted. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the stream inserter is defined in the source file for the `Duration` class and not in the header; that would account for the undefined reference, since it's inline. If that's the case, move the inline definition into the header.

There's a problem in the addition, too: what happens if **both** minutes and seconds overflow? The first `if` statement will catch the minutes overflow and return a `Duration` object with its seconds out of range. It's probably simpler to create the new object without regard to overflow, then check for seconds overflowing and, if necessary, handle it, then check for minutes overflowing and, if necessary, handle it. And now you know why most date/time libraries use an integral type to store the number of seconds (or whatever) past the epoch instead of breaking out the details like this.

Comment: I've moved my 3rd condition (both mins and secs) to the top of the method and seems to work perfectly now. Ive tested when mins overflow, secs overflow and both overflow :D Unless there's anything else you can spot?

Comment: @qwertyRocker - no, that should make it work. It's more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the method for the << operator. For now, cout cannot parse your Duration.

Comment: When you look at this error message (this part in particular `class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Duration const &)`), you notice that the << operator is causing the problem here. StevieG did explain that better than me.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with this line
`cout << result << endl;`

You are trying to use the << operator on an object while you only overloaded the + operator
try:
`cout << result.getHours() << endl;`